# Получить имя категории по ID категории

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Здравствуйте.
Пушу свой маленький плагин на вордпрес, на вордпресе установлен вукомерс.
В одном месте я вытаскиваю id и Имена ВСЕХ категорий через `get_terms();`
А в другом месте мне нужно вытягивать ИМЯ категории по id
Поначалу думал что функция `get_cat_name( $cat_id )` не работает, ибо по ид категорий не возвращала нечего.
Но `get_categories()`відала мне такой вот результат:
[image: вывод функции <code>get_categories</code>]
внизу в рамочку я выделил уже вывод  `get_cat_name( $cat_id )`категории "1";
в итоге я так понимаю не подтягиваются все категории, я их создал 4 (категории вукомерса)
как мене решить проблемку? может нужно подключать файлы вукомерса, или обьявлять глобалные переменные 
благодарю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В WooCommerce не категории, а таксономии.

```
$term  = get_term_by( 'id', $id, 'product_cat');
```

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось!